# Magento grid header change align to center

Tags: magento

The header in Magento's grid is aligned to left by default. You can easily change the align in cell by adding 'align' parameter to column definition.

But how can I change the align of header on Adminhtml Grid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add this to the column definition.

```
'header_css_class'=>'a-center'
```

So your column can look like this:

```
$this->addColumn('some_column', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('some_helper')->__('Header title'),
    'index'     => 'some_column',
    'header_css_class'=>'a-center'
));
```

The `header_css_class` parameter allows you to set a class to the grid header and `a-center` is the admin class for `text-align:center`.

*Off topic but maybe you need it:*
`column_css_class` allows you to add a class to the columns that hold values.

Comment: thank you man, I just figured it out by myself by seeng this method:
getHeaderCssClass()